# Looking for young adult book about boy who wishes to be a farmer/gardener

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I am looking for a young adult book, probably written in the late 60's to mid 70's, it was a dystopian future where people seemed to be set in for specific roles.  The main character, a boy, wanted to be a farmer or gardener, while society was dictating he should be something else.  There was something about a food shortage, or control of food, such that him being a farmer or gardener was somehow forbidden.  I can't really recall more than that.  Mostly the story was about how the boy learned secretly how to raise plants and with another (perhaps a girl) escaped the place he lived.

I know not much to go on, but it's one I recall liking when I was young but can't remember more of the story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like it could be Frank Bonham's [The Missing Person's League](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/527452.The_Missing_Persons_League), first published in 1976:

- In a dying, resource-starved world, food production is strictly controlled, and private food growing is prohibited
- The protagonist and his father create a secret garden below their house (having stored the excavated soil in the walls) and have encounters with a investigating resource policeman.
- He meets a girl who is the key to the larger plot (the mysterious disappearances of large numbers of people)

Eventually, we learn the reason for the disappearances, and they escape:

> The disappeared people have actually been recruited to enter suspended animation in hidden bunkers; they will emerge after the ecosystem has re-established itself following a mass extinction

I enjoyed it as a youth, though I recall there are a couple of plot points that seemed hokey, particularly the

> hypnotic mind-control of the girl and the ending with the bad guys meeting their end in an Indiana Jones-style facemelting booby-trap

Comment: This is it, the secret garden part is what I remember.  Forgot the suspended animation part, but that is the end and the synopsis matches.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Possibly [Robert A. Heinlein's Farmer in the Sky](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439132771)

[image: farmer-1] [image: farmer-2] [image: farmer-3] [image: farmer-4] [image]

There are a *LOT* of different covers for this book. Above are a few of the older ones.

> The Earth is crowded and food is rationed, but a colony on Ganymede,
>   one of the moons of Jupiter, offers an escape for teenager Bill Lermer
>   and his family. Back on Earth, the move sounded like a grand
>   adventure, but Bill soon realizes that life on the frontier is
>   dangerous, and in an alien world with no safety nets, nature is
>   cruelly unforgiving of even small mistakes. Bill’s new home is a world
>   of unearthly wonders—and heartbreaking tragedy. He will face
>   hardships, survive dangers, and grow up fast, meeting the challenge of
>   opening up a new world for humanity and finding strengths within
>   himself that he had never suspected existed.

Comment: That _does_ match the 'farmer' criterion, but little else. Have you read it recently?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what it accomplishes to post all those covers

Comment: I'd remember Heinlein, besides there wasn't any off world in the story I remember.  An interesting read though.

Comment: @Richard: When trying to remember a book from years ago, covers are often the thing people remember best (Sometimes the only thing).In this case there are a lot of covers - which one might help the OP? I chose a few that looked like they might be from the right time-frame. At least they're not page-filling images, at least not on my screen.

Comment: @JoeL. - They're more obtrusive on mobile

Comment: @Richard: As John Fogerty said, "It's all right now, I learned my lesson well, You see you can't please everyone, so you got to please yourself."

Answer (score -1):

It's a short story called, Brian's world.

Comment: Can provide any more details? For example, some quotes or reviews that show how this matches the question?